# Extends Decision Table in Drools

Tags: drools

As Drools provide a facility to extends Rules, same way i need to extends decision table.

Actually I have set of Master Rules and Master Decision Tables which needs to be reused. Drools provided a functionality for extending Rules, but i don't know about  Decision tables. Purpose of this functionality is we need to reuse Rules and DTA, and also its easy to maintain single copy.

Can some guild me and provide a steps to achieve same functionality.

```
rule "Base"
    when
       eval(true)
    then
        System.out.println("Base will fire if Object.condition1 evaluates to true");
end

rule "ExtensionOfBase" extends "Base"
    when
      eval(true)
    then
        System.out.println("Base will fire if Object.condition1 and Object.condition2 evaluates to true");
end
```

Comment: I'm completely at a loss what you mean by "facility to extend DRLs", so asking for the "same way" for decision tables is absolutely unclear.

Comment: Changed Question. I mean to ask Drools provide extends with Rules, Is there any way to extends Decision tables?

Comment: That would mean adding columns to a part of a spreadsheet - sorry, no, there's nothing like that provided by Drools.